# Ping command works in Network utility but not in terminal

Tags: network, ping

I am on os x 10.9.4

If I ping google from the network utility I get 0% packet loss.

But if I try to ping google from the terminal with `ping www.google.com` I get 100% packet loss. System Preferences -> Firewall shows it is turned off.

What else might be happening?

Comment: that is ping google.com (without www)

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message you get when you are pinging from the terminal?

try an nslookup www.google.com and make sure that your dns is resolving correctly